# data frame string search in a custom function

Tags: r, string, dataframe, search

I'm trying to write a function that will search for a given string in a data frame. For example:

```
# Set up
library(tidyverse)
options(stringsAsFactors= F)

color <- c('black', 'black', 'blue', 'blue', 'yellow')
vehicle <- c('truck', 'truck', 'car', 'car', 'bike')
plant <- c('tree', 'flower', 'grass', 'tree', 'flower')
height <- c('tall', 'medium', 'short', 'tall', 'medium')

testdf <- as.data.frame(cbind(color, vehicle, plant, height))
```

Make a function to search for any variable that has a value of truck in any row:

```
search.func <- function(df) {
  names(df %>%
    select_if(is.character) %>%
    select_if(grepl('truck', .)))
}

search.func(testdf)  # returns the correct result - 'vehicle'
```

To make the function more flexible, and be able to pass any string, I've tried:

```
search.func2 <- function(df, string) {

  string <- enquo(string)

  names(df %>%
          select_if(is.character) %>%
          select_if(grepl(string, .)))
  }

search.func2(testdf, truck)  # errors out
```

But I'm not use the enquo properly - I need the quotes in the grepl function and I'm having trouble telling R how to do it. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Why not make your function `string=` input `"truck"` and avoid the quoting/unquoting? I understand the motivation to not have to quote column names etc, but even the tidyverse `stringr` packages don't use symbols to represent text strings stored inside vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Adding `quo_name` you should be fine .

```
search.func2 <- function(df, string) {

  string <- enquo(string)
  string <- quo_name(string)
  names(df %>%
          select_if(is.character) %>%
          select_if(grepl(string, .)))
}

#search.func2(testdf, truck)
#[1] "vehicle"
```